# jquery chosen not showing dropdown in django admin

Tags: django, jquery-chosen

I tried to use jquery chosen in django admin and it is not showing dropdown after implementing. With some debug I can confirm that the dropdown is there but not showing due to some css issue.

Any help ?

Comment: You need to give more info. Best to show the code that doesn't work

Comment: If there are any JS errors in the console, then do share it!